# why is DF['date'] = [re.findall("(-)(-)", i) for i in DF['date']] not working?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem with the extraction
Given is a column Date, where I want to extract the months
for example: 2022-05-12 --> 05

How can I programm this?

```
import pandas as pd
import re
DF = pd.DataFrame({
    "item_id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "costumer": ["CG", "MD", "CC", "CZ"],
    "Betrag": [150, 12, 78, 56],
    "games": [["Minecraft", "Uno"], ["WOW", "Minecraft"], ["WOW", "Minecraft"], ["WOW", "Minecraft", "The last of us"]], 
    "date": ["2022-11-18", "2022-09-12", "2022-08-26", "2022-05-12"]
})

DF['date'] = [re.findall("(-)(-)", i) for i in DF['date']]
DF
```

Expected Output: each row in date:
11
09
08
05

Comment: The pattern `"(-)(-)"` will find two dashes next to each other.  None of your date values match that pattern.  Your date values have two dashes **with numbers in between**, which that pattern does not match.

Comment: your regex is incorrect yes, but why aren't you using to_datetime and extracting the month using `dt.month`?

Comment: `DF['date'] = [d.split('-')[1] for d in DF['date']]` should work.

Comment: @cs95 - thanks, I didn't know, that this function exists :)

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm curious what the solution might be. Could you please write the solution down?

Comment: It's also working: 
`DF["month"] = pd.datetime(DF["date"]).dt.month`